# Calculate the words number in a view in mysql

Tags: mysql, view

I have the following table structure

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| myID            | text        |
+-----------------+-------------+
| 3               | some text   |
| 3               | other text  |
| 5               | text        |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

myID is not a unique ID. It can be repeated. Text is arbitrary strings.
I'm looking to create a view that returns the count of words in the *text* of the myID rows.

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| myID            | count       |
+-----------------+-------------+
| 3               | 4           |
| 5               | 1           |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Well, I started out (I'm a newbie is mySQL) and did the following

```
SELECT 
myid,
pagetext
FROM table
GROUP by myid
```

This does just the grouping. I think the next steps are

1. How to make pagetext returns the concatenation of the appropriate myID rows (I'm looking to limit the concatenation to 25 rows only).
2. How to count the number of words in the returned value.

Any ideas how to start?

Comment: Start with trying to define "What constitutes a word?" It isn't nearly as easy as it sounds, unless the data is stored so that it always has a single space separating words and no punctuation.

Comment: Also, does is the count of TOTAL words or UNIQUE words for each ID?

Comment: Just characters separated by a space. It counts the Total words, not sure why you were confused. The example actually showed it.

Comment: I assumed the example didn't include every possible combination of inputs. Any reason why the words aren't stored separately in another table. That would make your life much easier.

Comment: I don't have control over the structure of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the number of words in a column (if you can assume there is 1 and exactly 1 space between words) with the following query:

```
SELECT
  myId,
  SUM(LENGTH(text)-LENGTH(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''))+1)
FROM table
GROUP BY myId
```

Source: http://www.mwasif.com/2008/12/count-number-of-words-in-a-mysql-column/

Comment: ...except you missed one instance of 'name' from the source; it should be: `SUM(LENGTH(text)-LENGTH(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''))+1)`

Comment: What about limitation? It's much needed. How can I add it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, 25 rows. Can I suggest you ask it as another question?

Comment: Yes, only 25 rows of the corresponding "myId" ID.